# Unable to Mange DNS via MMC

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

When trying to access the DNS service on  Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (Build 3790) domain controller/schema master via the MMC DNS snap in or locally via the DNS MMC from Administrative tools I'm getting a red "X" through the icon for the DNS Server. The inability to access DNS management via MMC happens on all domain controllers as well.

We've looked at items such as the DHCP client not being started, incorrect DNS setup ( the machine points at itself and another DC ), the DNS service not running ( it is and all DNS queries via NSLOOKUP work correctly ), dslint returns the correct information and functions as expected.

There is the following entry in the DNS event log:

```
The DNS server could not initialize the remote procedure call (RPC) service. If it is not running, start the RPC service or reboot the computer. The event data is the error code.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

0000: 0000051b
```

dnscmd fails with RPC server unavailable yet RPC is started:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.DOMAIN>dnscmd /Info
Info query failed
    status = 1722 (0x000006ba)

Command failed:  RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE     1722  (000006ba)
```

DCDIAG /TEST:DNS /V /E produces the following errors:

```
    Warning: no DNS RPC connectivity (error or non Microsoft DNS server is running)
          [Error details: 1753 (Type: Win32 - Description: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.)]

                 Warning: no DNS RPC connectivity (error or non Microsoft DNS server is running)
          [Error details: 1722 (Type: Win32 - Description: The RPC server is unavailable.)]

          The DNS server could not initialize the remote procedure call (RPC) service. If it is not running, start the RPC service or reboot the computer. The event data is the error code.
```

A DNS query for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs. returns the correct results.

All domain and ADS related activities are working except that I can't manage my DNS via MMC or dnscmd.

Any thoughts or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Adding Registry export per request:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   10/18/2012 - 2:29 PM
Value 0
  Name:            DCOM Protocols
  Type:            REG_MULTI_SZ
  Data:            ncacn_ip_tcp

Value 1
  Name:            UuidSequenceNumber
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0xb19bd0f


Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\ClientProtocols
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   3/9/2007 - 12:11 PM
Value 0
  Name:            ncacn_np
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            rpcrt4.dll

Value 1
  Name:            ncacn_ip_tcp
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            rpcrt4.dll

Value 2
  Name:            ncadg_ip_udp
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            rpcrt4.dll

Value 3
  Name:            ncacn_http
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            rpcrt4.dll

Value 4
  Name:            ncacn_at_dsp
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            rpcrt4.dll


Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\NameService
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   2/20/2006 - 4:48 PM
Value 0
  Name:            DefaultSyntax
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            3

Value 1
  Name:            Endpoint
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            \pipe\locator

Value 2
  Name:            NetworkAddress
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            \\.

Value 3
  Name:            Protocol
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            ncacn_np

Value 4
  Name:            ServerNetworkAddress
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            \\.


Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\NetBios
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   2/20/2006 - 4:48 PM

Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\RpcProxy
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   3/9/2007 - 12:11 PM
Value 0
  Name:            Enabled
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1

Value 1
  Name:            ValidPorts
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            pdc:100-5000


Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\SecurityService
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   2/20/2006 - 4:48 PM
Value 0
  Name:            9
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            secur32.dll

Value 1
  Name:            10
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            secur32.dll

Value 2
  Name:            14
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            schannel.dll

Value 3
  Name:            16
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            secur32.dll

Value 4
  Name:            1
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            secur32.dll

Value 5
  Name:            18
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            secur32.dll

Value 6
  Name:            68
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            netlogon.dll
```

Comment: Can you add an export of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet to your question?

Comment: Adding export of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet

Comment: Wow that's totally fubar, and you covered all the bases I would have probably asked. I'd be paying for a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Agreed. It's a very puzzling issue. It's almost as if it's a permission issue. Could the admin account be being denied access to the service in someway?

Comment: I'm going to try removing DNS from one of the DC's and re-adding it.